# For the function $y=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-e^x}$, prove that there is one horizontal asymptote at $y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

$$y=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x-e^x}$$

Proving vertical asymptotes are easy but when it comes to proving horizontal or oblique ones, I often get stuck. This function seems to intersect its asymptote at the origin so substituting in $0$ to show an error does not work. So how does one prove these kinds of things, is there a common way that people use? Right now, I am suspecting something to do with limits(correct me if I am wrong) but have no idea how to progress with that way.

Comment: One wouldn't say "horizontal asymptote at $x=0$". Instead one would say that the line (defined by the equation) $y=0$ is a horizontal asymptote as $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: Right, sry, that was my mistake, thanks for pointing that out. I will update it otherwise it sounds like a vertical asymptote

Answer (score 2):

A function has a horizontal asymptote at $0$ if
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0,\; \text{or} \;\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=0.$$

In this case the function is only defined on the positive real line, so to prove it has a horizontal asymptote at $0$ you need to show that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt x }{x-e^x} =0 .$$

The general method for evaluting this limit is to divide by the highest order term on the denominator and use algebra of limits. So, try and find
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\sqrt x}{e^x} }{\frac x {e^x}-1} $$
instead.

Comment: So it is always the highest order term(like for all situations with horizontal and oblique asymptotes)?

Comment: Dividing by the highest order term is just a method for finding the limit of fractions. You'll probably be doing it a lot when working with limits